# What does << mean in groovy

Tags: groovy, gradle

I am trying to read some groovy and came across the "double less than" `<<` in a couple contexts.  It is hard to google.  How does it work in these examples?

```
new URL('the url').withInputStream{ i -> f.withOutputStream{ it << i }}
```

and in Gradle:

```
task hello << {
  println 'Hello world!'
}
```

Comment: The more general answer by @cfrick is correct. In the Gradle context the left shift operator is overloaded to add a task action. See the [`Task`](https://gradle.org/docs/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Task.html#leftShift(groovy.lang.Closure)) documentation for details.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In regular Java (and pretty much anywhere else) it means a bitwise left shift on numbers:

```
assert (1<<4)==16
```

But Groovy allows [overloading operators](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/next/html/documentation/#Operator-Overloading) and in the examples mentioned it is means, what it is overloaded with (use of the method `a.leftShift(b)`).  Like in C++ it is usually used to signal "append" operations (e.g. `std::cout << "Hello World" << std::endl`).

In above examples it means, "append the stream" (see https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/blob/GROOVY_2_4_X/src/main/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/IOGroovyMethods.java#L113) or "add this functionality/closure to the task" (see https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/RB_2.0/subprojects/core/src/main/groovy/org/gradle/api/internal/AbstractTask.java#L460).

There also is e.g. `<<` to append items to a regular list (e.g. `def list = []; list << 42`).

If you want to use this for your own, you basically can do arbitrary things with it.  In the following example "add five to `cnt`"

```
class X {
    def cnt = 0
    def leftShift(x) {
        cnt += 5
    }
}

def x = new X()
x << "lol"
assert x.cnt == 5
```

Is is smart?  Maybe not.  You most likely would add functionality, that is needed often and makes sense for the operator.  And beware of the precedence of the `<<` operator!